# using subprocess pipe and stderr for one command

Tags: python

Basically, I am trying to run the command (in linux)

```
chrome http://www.google.com | cleanup.py
```

and trying to log stderr to a file.

```
with open("/tmp/chrome-logs.txt", 'a') as tempf:
        run_pipe = subprocess.Popen( ["-c", "cleanup.py"] , stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=tempf, shell=True)
        run_pipe.communicate("chrome","http://www.google.com")
```

How do I get this to work?

I could however use subprocess.call to execute, but is that the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
stderr=open(<file name>', 'w')
```

And then you do not need *communicate*, you may also just use *call* instead of *Popen*